# null context exception in android application class

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have a class that extends `Application` which has a a function that needs to use a context and I receive an `NullPointerException` -> `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

Here is my class:

```
class AppUtils : Application() {

    fun hideApp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "hideApp() called")
        val appComponent = ComponentName(applicationContext, "SplashActivity")
        applicationContext.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                appComponent,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

    }
}
```

I also declared the class in the application tag in manifest..
Any idea what is the problem? I tried every type of context (applicationContext,baseContext) but all are null

Comment: How are you invoking this `hideApp` function?

Comment: from inside a `JobIntentService`

Comment: Calling the class `AppUtils` smells like you are instantiating it yourself, and that won't work. In a `JobIntentService` you can use the service itself as a `Context`.

Comment: Ideally, your [mcve] would show the code where you are calling `hideApp()`.